# Out of ideas on how to revive the Gateway E-9525R server

Tags: restore, hardware

My boss gave me a project: he got a Gateway E-9525R server that does not do anything at startup. He asked if I could revive it somehow. No one is really sure what happened to it, rumor has it the BIOS flashing went wrong.

When it starts, I get no video, the monitor stays in the power save mode (attached over VGA, I tried the front and back connectors). The motherboard has 8 LEDs that issue error codes, and most of the time the error code is E1, the explanation for it is not in the server manual.

I tried restoring BIOS, resetting BIOS settings, and followed the other suggestions (from the manual) to restore BIOS, but it still does not react to anything.

What else can I do to get it to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- send it to gigabyte for repair
- find another identical server and try to swap pieces (motherboard, daugterboards, cpus, ram, psu, etc...) until you find the failed one, then order it new
- find out it has a socketed flash chip for the BIOS (unlikely, I guess), and if you find it just take it out, go search a compatible flash chip and flash it with a new bios

Comment: +1 from me, but I don't have enough reputation on this web site to do it :) . Great suggestions. I will talk to my boss about potentially sending it for repairs. I don't have an identical server, so I can't troubleshoot it that way, unfortunately. 

The BIOS is not socketed, I checked that already. I'd unsolder it, but this is a pet project, so I was mostly wondering if there were any quick fixes. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: If it's not socketed it's probably not soldered either but integrated in some other package (usually in some LPC bus chip or other part of the chipset). Or maybe it's soldered but it's a smallish SMD chip.

PS, if you're going to follow an answer you can flag it as accepted even without the +1 :)